# Rails: Sort posts by number of likes in socialization gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using the https://github.com/cmer/socialization to allow the user to like Posts, I want to write a query to sort Posts by the number of likes.

This is the result from `y Like.all` in rails c

```
  Like Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes"
--- !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Relation
klass: &1 !ruby/class 'Like'
table: &2 !ruby/object:Arel::Table
  name: likes
  engine: *1
  columns:
  aliases: []
  table_alias:
  primary_key:
values: {}
offsets: {}
loaded: true
should_eager_load: false
arel: !ruby/object:Arel::SelectManager
  engine: *1
  ctx: &3 !ruby/object:Arel::Nodes::SelectCore
    source: !ruby/object:Arel::Nodes::JoinSource
      left: *2
      right: []
    top:
    set_quantifier:
    projections:
    - !ruby/struct:Arel::Attributes::Attribute
      relation: *2
      name: !ruby/object:Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral '*'
    wheres: []
    groups: []
    having:
    windows: []
  bind_values: []
  ast: !ruby/object:Arel::Nodes::SelectStatement
    cores:
    - *3
    orders: []
    limit:
    lock:
    offset:
    with:
records:
- !ruby/object:Like
  attributes:
    id: 22
    liker_type: User
    liker_id: 1
    likeable_type: Post
    likeable_id: 1
    created_at: 2015-03-07 17:08:06.133777000 Z
- !ruby/object:Like
  attributes:
    id: 23
    liker_type: User
    liker_id: 2
    likeable_type: Post
    likeable_id: 1
    created_at: 2015-03-07 17:14:40.734607000 Z
- !ruby/object:Like
  attributes:
    id: 25
    liker_type: User
    liker_id: 1
    likeable_type: Post
    likeable_id: 7
    created_at: 2015-03-08 04:59:17.948646000 Z
- !ruby/object:Like
  attributes:
    id: 26
    liker_type: User
    liker_id: 1
    likeable_type: Post
    likeable_id: 8
    created_at: 2015-03-13 08:07:18.672987000 Z
- !ruby/object:Like
  attributes:
    id: 27
    liker_type: User
    liker_id: 2
    likeable_type: Post
    likeable_id: 8
    created_at: 2015-03-13 08:07:47.133997000 Z
 => nil
```

Where `likeable_id` is the Post ID

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just solved this by sorting in the for loop in views like

```
- @posts.sort { |a,b| b.likers(User).count <=> a.likers(User).count }.each do |post|
```

`likers(User).count` is the socialization gem way of getting the likes count for a single post.

Inspired by : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771519/558777